# SQL Group by returning wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a salary table in which I am trying to return determine the **lowest salary earned** and by which **industry** for **each year** however despite getting the correct lowest salary earned I am receiving the wrong industry name.

I am aware that it is due to the fact that I have utilized `GROUP BY` without placing a constraint(?) on it hence it is returning me the wrong value but I am not sure how I can solve it.

**SALARY TABLE**

- salaryID
- salaryAmount
- salaryYear
- industryName (ForeignKey)

Can someone please guide me on the right path?

```
    **(Problem Code)**
    SELECT MIN(S.salary), S.industryName, S.salaryYear
    FROM salary
    GROUP BY S.salaryYear;



    **(Attempted solution)**
    SELECT S.salary
    FROM salary
    INNER JOIN 
    SELECT (min(S1.amount)), S1.year, S1.industryName, S1.salaryId 
    FROM salary S1 
    GROUP BY S1.year
    ON S.salaryId = S1.salaryId);
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Could you build an example on dbfiddle and show which result you will want to see for that example

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  Why is `S1.industryName` is not in `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @eric theres a syntax error in the solution where i cant even run the code to try

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  Any non-aggregated columns must be included in `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT MIN(amount), year
FROM salary
GROUP BY year
```

If you want to include industryName,

```
SELECT amount, year, industryName, salaryId
FROM (
    SELECT amount, year, industryName, salaryId 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY amount) AS rn
    FROM salary
 ) a
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Pre-MySQL 8 version

```
SELECT *
FROM salary s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(amount) AS minAmount, year
    FROM salary
    GROUP BY year
) m ON m.minAmount = s.amount AND m.year = s.year
```

Comment: i do not want to get the lowest salary for each specific industry for each year though i want to get the lowest salary earned by any of the industries for each year

Comment: @YeoBryan industryName grouping removed.

Comment: i tried to copy the cope over but it says there is some syntax error and prevents me from using that code =/

Comment: I suppose your syntax error is due to your DB version is prior to 8, so can't use window analytic functions, can you? @YeoBryan

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i am actually on version "10.4.6-MariaDB"

Comment: @YeoBryan Then why can't my `ROW_NUMBER()` function work?  It should work.

Comment: @YeoBryan Just missing a comma.  Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Things like missing comma, mis-spelt column names, wrong column names, you should be able to figure out by yourself since you have the error and the data.  We don't have the data or the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a self-join :

```
SELECT s1.industryName, s2.min_salary, s2.salaryYear
  FROM salary s1
  JOIN  
  (
   SELECT MIN(salary) as min_salary, salaryYear
    FROM salary
   GROUP BY salaryYear
   ) s2
    ON s1.salary = s2.min_salary
   AND s1.salaryYear = s2.salaryYear;
```

<kbd>[The Demo of this query with your sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9894ff5043e3bf6ef988e4b681e0e393)</kbd>

Comment: its returning me the minimum salary but its still returning the wrong industry name, any idea how to rectify that

Comment: is it possible to share your sample data within a fiddle ..? @YeoBryan

Comment: is this how it works? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fe6jqe4Bhv9F82UsnenJCb/0# . sorry i am not really good at this

Comment: doesn't matter, but you have an extra `industryName`,which I commented out since I have no `industryName` column within the subquery, in your fiddle. Please have a look at : [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cjnupAqLjjPcKDETHGaWeV/0) which works well.